# Как получить данные первоночальной строки js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. В общем было у меня в html:

```
<div id="comments" >
  <p class="read-more">Какой-то текст много символов</p>
</div>
<div id="comments" >
  <p class="read-more">Какой-то текст много символов</p>
</div>
```

Через jquery я сделал: Если больше 199 символов отображает "Показать весь текст", и в этот момент показывает только 199 символов

Код:

```
$(".read-more").each(function (index) {
    var readMoreHtml = $(this).text();
    var reduce = readMoreHtml.substr(0, 199);

    if (readMoreHtml) {
      $(this).html(reduce).append("<a href='' class='read-more-link' style='color:red'> Показать весь текст</a>");
    } else {
      $(this).html(readMoreHtml);
    }
});
```

Таким образом получилось в html

```
<p class="read-more">текст <a href="">Показать весь текст</a></p>
<p class="read-more">текст <a href="">Показать весь текст</a></p>
```

Update: Решил сам, чуть по другому

Comment: Просто вы должны менять метод отображения минимального текста, вы удаляете часть текста. и как хотите опять вернуть его?

Comment: Не особо понял вопрос, если Вы про то то что после "показать больше" возвращал текст, то это я сделал.

Answer (score 1):

> Теперь вопрос, как мне получить из другой функции - полный текст сразу, не нажимая "показать больше"

Возвращаете полный текст из первой функции, записываете в переменную и передаете во вторую функцию.

Comment: Ну это понятно, а вот сделать не получается

Comment: за вас написать что ли?

Comment: вам надо разбить код на функции, тогда все станет понятно.

Comment: Было бы неплохо если бы написал, примерно как это можно сделать, то пробывал через "window" переменную получить не получается.
А от такого ответа, что ты дал, толку нет

Comment: повторяю, разбейте код на функции и тогда все станет понятно.

Comment: Спасибо (нет). Решил уже другим способом. 
$(".read-more-link").click(); 
Хоть и не особо способ, потом подумаю как по другому

Comment: Вежливость - это не ваше, я понял. Обращайтесь.

Comment: Хотел еще спросить, то хз.
Допустим скрываю я текст через js(display:none).
Как лучше: вместо этого текста вставить, прописать в html
дать ему область видимости display:none, и через js убрать display none или через js создать элемент? Как больше будет по стандарту js и более корректно

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("body").on('click', ".read-more-link", function () {
  var p = $(this).parent();
  p.text(p.data('text'));
})

$(".read-more").each(function (index) {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  var text = $this.text();
  var short = text.substr(0, 10);
  
  var link = "<a href='#' class='read-more-link'>Показать весь текст</a>";
  
  $this.text(short).data('text', text).append(link);
});
```

```css
.read-more-link {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="comments">
  <p class="read-more">Какой-то текст много символов</p>
  <p class="read-more">Какой-то текст много символов</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но уже исправил проблему